# Why getResources().getString() return null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-resources, android-dialogfragment

I always get `NullPointerException` whenever I call:

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);
```

I called it from `DialogFragment` in my `Activity`. I also tried using `getActivity()`, but that didn't work for me too. Does anybody have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Can You post a little bit more of Your code? It is important when You call this....

Comment: can you give the complete code I would like to see to which variable exactly are you assigning this to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

If you write this in a fragment:

```
String[] days = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);
```

If you write this in an activity:

```
String[] days = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);
```

Comment: I used this in activity: getApplication().getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days); and this in fragment: getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);

Comment: Nah, no need to get application then get application context. Do it like how I said. :)

Answer (score 3):

It´s just an assumption, but mostly if somebody gets this error, they make a mistake where the code is placed or when they call it. For example, if you call it before onCreate():

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

private String foo = "foo";
private String[] yourArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourArray);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ...
    }
}
```

This will result in a NullPointerException. Instead you have to call it like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

private String foo = "foo";
private String[] yourArray;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
        yourArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{
Context mContext;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);   
       mContext = this;                  
}

class DialogFragment{
 String[] days = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);
...............
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!